# Is there any reason Backup & Migrate leaves all the .info files around?

Tags: backups

I just discovered that there are hundreds of `.info` files left lying around in the folder that the Backup & Migrate module uses for scheduled backups, while only 12 of these have a corresponding `.gz` file.

Is there a reason to keep these?  Do they have any real value?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any value to keeping them.  To get rid of them, you can do something like this

```
cd /private/backup_migrate/scheduled  # where ever you keep this
for file in *.info; do gz_file=`echo "$file" | sed -e 's/.info//'`; if [[ ! -f "${gz_file}" ]]; then rm -f "${file}"; fi; done
```

This will preserve all `*.info` files that correspond to a `*.gz` file, and delete the rest.  It *appears* to be an oversight on the part of the Backup & Migrate module to leave all of these lying around.   (Apologies in advance to the module's maintainers if I'm mistaken on this:  I do not mean to be critical, and I appreciate your work!)

If you want to wrap all this up into a quick alias or function, you can put something like this into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or whatever:

```
function cleanup_backups(){ 
  pushd /<youfillinthispart>/private/backup_migrate/scheduled
  for file in *.info; do
    gz_file=`echo "$file" | sed -e 's/.info//'` 
    if [[ ! -f "${gz_file}" ]]; then
      rm -f "${file}"
    fi
  done
  pushd
}
```

(You'll have to make it a bit more complicated if you have subdirectories in your scheduled backups folder, but this should get you started.)

Comment: Check out http://drupal.org/node/1555742